# Usage of 'next' request parameter in flask-login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app. In it I have the following function, which is working correctly:

```
@blueprint.route("/home/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    # Handle logging in
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            login_user(form.user)
            flash("You are logged in.", 'success')
            redirect_url = request.args.get("next") or url_for("user.profile")
            return redirect(redirect_url)
        else:
            flash_errors(form)
    return render_extensions("public/home.html", form=form)
```

In the line:

```
redirect_url = request.args.get("next") or url_for("user.profile")
```

I don't understand the purpose of 'request.args.get("next")' . In my case when I look at the request object:

```
>>> request.args
ImmutableMultiDict([])
>>> request.args.get("next")
>>>
```

I've been reading the docs (https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and many stackoverflow questions, but am still not sure I understand why and how 'next' is used.

Answer (score 2):

The next parameter serves to say to which url the client should be redirected
after successful login. It serves to cover the following scenario:
Client enters the url

```
www.abcd.com/profile
```

Let's say this route should only be accessible to authenticated users (it is decorated with the login_required decorator). 
If the client is not authenticated he will be redirected to the login page, and the next parameter wil be set to /profile so that if the authentication is successful the user will be redirected to the profile page.

Comment: Thanks that, helps. Regarding "If the client is not authenticated he will be redirected to the login page, and the next parameter wil be set to /profile so that if the authentication is successful the user will be redirected to the profile page." I'm not sure I understand how that is set up, can you direct me to a code sample or clarify this further please?